# Subscript alignment problem with \int\limits

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, underbrace

When subscript in the expression `\int\limits_{some stuff}` is large, it seems that LaTeX underestimates the space occupied by the subscript which leads to the wrong placement of e.g. `\left\lvert` (vertical line touches the subscript, with no spacing in between). The issue is absent when `\sum` is used instead of `\int`, and the spacing on the left side looks good in this case. Similarly, using `underbrace` on `\int\limits_{some stuff}` creates a bracket shifted by around a millimeter to the right which again looks weird. As before, everything works well for `\sum` instead of `\int\limits`. Why is it so and how can the behavior of `\int\limits` be fixed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\left\lvert\int\limits_{0000000}\right\rvert\]
\[\underbrace{\int\limits_{0000000}}\]
\[\left\lvert\sum_{0000000}\right\rvert\]
\[\left\lvert\sum\limits_{0000000}\right\rvert\] %\limits doesn't impact \sum behavior as expected
\[\underbrace{\sum_{0000000}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference between both symbols comes from the italic correction. According to rule 13a in appendix G of The TeXbook, the lower limits are [shifted left](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web#:%7E:text=shift_amount(x)%3A%3Dhalf(delta)) by half the italic correction (and the upper limits shifted right). And the [integral sign](https://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/cm/mf/bigop.mf#:%7E:text=%5Cdisplaystyle%20integral%20sign) has an italic correction of `8u#` whereas the [summation sign](https://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/cm/mf/bigop.mf#:%7E:text=%5Cdisplaystyle%20summation%20sign) has none.

You can circumvent this by replacing the symbol `\int` with an Op nucleus `\mathop{\int}`, because rule 13 says that for non-symbols, an italic correction is disregarded.

```tex
$$\left\vert\int\limits_{0000000}\right\vert$$
$$\left\vert\mathop{\int}\limits_{0000000}\right\vert$$
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can compute the width of the italic correction and use it for countermeasures, such as inserting a kern after the left bar and a negative kern before the right bar. You need to know that the big integral sign is character 0x5A in the (plain TeX) font `\tenex`.

```tex
\newdimen\intcorr
{\setbox0=\hbox{\tenex\char"5A\/\global\dimen\intcorr=\lastkern}}
$$\left\vert\kern.5\dimen\intcorr\int\limits_{0000000}\kern-.5\dimen\intcorr\right\vert$$
```

[image]

Comment: And what if I prefer shifted subscripts, but want to align `\lvert` and `\rvert` accordingly? If no nice and automatic solution is possible, I could perhaps manually introduce some `\hspace', but I've never seen the unit `u#` and LaTeX seems not to recognize it. How can I convert it to pt or em?

Comment: See my edited answer.