# Wrong spacing with math mode inside sl in plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, kerning

Here is a minimal example of a problem I encounter sometimes:

```
{\sl Let $\cal U$ be}
\bye
```

In the output *U* is much closer to "Let" than to "be".
Is there an equivalent to the italic correction to be applied?

Comment: Almost the same as [fonts - Bad spacing of math letters within italic text - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/bad-spacing-of-math-letters-within-italic-text?noredirect=1&lq=1) except for plain TeX versus LaTeX (actually the other question doesn't specify that it's LaTeX either, so it applies to both). Basically there's no easy solution apart from hard coding correction factor for every character.

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/631081/255231) for how to determine the italic correction for a given character.

Comment: I see, Thann you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX automatically adds the italic correction after a math character, in this situation.

In select cases, you can remove this italic correction:

```
\def\nocorr{_{\kern-\scriptspace}}

1. Let $\cal U$ be

2. Let $\cal U\nocorr$ be

3. {\sl Let $\cal U$ be}

4. {\sl Let\/ $\cal U$ be}

5. {\sl Let\/ $\cal U\nocorr$ be}

\bye
```

The trick is that the italic correction is not inserted if there is a subscript but no superscript; however one has also to remove the `\scriptspace`.

Note the slight differece between lines 3 and 4.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so when should I use this trick? For cal specifically or anytime it looks wrong?

Comment: @Laravel It's not specific to `\cal`.